# Git (no branch) in xcode

Tags: xcode, git

In my ios project I use git as scm. Xcode listing of repositories includes something called (by xcode at least) "(no branch)". Some time ago I probably checked out a previous commit, without creating a branch. Since then I have made some 40 commits. Now I want to branch from my next last commit. I am a little worried what might happen and want to know how to get back to some decent branch structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did some commits while being in a detached head. You can still create a new branch that will point to the tip of the detached head:

```
 git checkout -b my_new_branch
```

This will create and checkout the new branch.